# Make a progress bar that increments on click and survives page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

It's a silly thing but I want to make a progress bar that updates by clicking a button. I want the progress bar to increment by 3.33% every time de user clicks a button. I wonder too how can I a save the value of the progress bar so every time the user enter the website it's not initialized on zero

Thank u everyone!

Sorry about not sharing my code. Though I was doing everything right.
This is what I had done so far. Using bootstrap

```
 <div class="container">
<br>
<p class="font-weight-bold" style="font-size:20px" id="inscritos">0 INSCRITOS | OBJETIVO <i
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i> 30</p>

<div class="progress">
  <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success active" role="progressbar"
    aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
    <p id="numero">0%</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="font-weight-bold" style="font-size:20px;text-align: center;"></p>
```

```
     window.addEventListener("load", inicio)
  function inicio(){
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", actualizarProgreso);
  }
  var progreso = 0;
  function actualizarProgreso() {
    var numero = document.getElementById("numero").textContent;
    localStorage.progreso = localStorage.getItem("progreso-ss");
    localStorage.progreso = parseInt(localStorage.progreso) + 1;
    document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.width = document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.width.length-1+3.33+'%';
    document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML = document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.width.length-1+3.33+'%';
  }
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

[image]

```js
const EL_progressBtn = document.querySelector("#progress-btn");
const EL_progressBar = document.querySelector("#progress-bar"); 

const barIncrement = () => {
  const progress = Math.min(parseFloat(localStorage.progress || "0"), 100);
  EL_progressBar.style.width = progress + "%";
};

EL_progressBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  localStorage.progress = parseFloat(localStorage.progress || "0") + 3.33;
  barIncrement(); // Do it on button click....
});

// ...and on page init:
barIncrement();
```

```css
#progress {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; width: 100vw;
  background: #eee;
  height: 10px;
}
#progress-bar {
  height: inherit;
  background: #0bf;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress"><div id="progress-bar"></div></div>
<button id="progress-btn">CLICK ME</button>
```

In case you want to **clear it** from storage (to i.e: restart the bar from the beginning) you could either:

```js
// On "Reset" button click:
delete localStorage.progress;
```

or

```js
// On "Reset" button click:
localStorage.removeItem("progress");
```